# How to map attribute value into two fields during Jackson deserialisation

Tags: java, jackson

I would like to know is there a way (probably using deserialiser) in Jackson to copy one attribute value to another object attribute the container has.

For example, `documentId` from the `TestData` class also needs to be persisted in the `Details.documentId` attribute.

json/TestData.json

```json
{
  "id": "1",
  "documentId" : "234234",
  "details" : {
    "name": "test",
    "lastName": "asdf"
  }
}
```

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor_ = @Autowired)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ExampleMicroserviceApplication.class,
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT
)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class TestDocumentId {

    final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Value("classpath:json/TestData.json")
    Resource testData;

    @SneakyThrows
    @Test
    void testDocumentIdPresentInDetails() {
        var data = objectMapper.readValue(testData.getFile(), TestData.class);
        assertThat(data.documentId).isNotNull();
        assertThat(data.getDetails().name).isNotNull();
        assertThat(data.getDetails().documentId).isNotNull();
    }

    @Data
    public static class TestData {
        private String id;
        private String documentId;
        private Details details;


        @Data
        public static class Details {
            private String documentId;
            private String name;
            private String lastName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does Lombok have to do with this question?

Comment: Oops, it's Jackson

Comment: Have you tried to implement a custom Deserializer? This is a class implementing the StdDeserializer. In there you should be able to do all dirty stuff :-)

Comment: Yes, tried but could not get hold of documentId field inside the Details object which is created by Jackson.

Comment: A deserializer is one of the ways to solve your issue, but if the attribute you want to copy is variable you can also modify the json string accordly to your expected result.